# find a basis for $U^⊥$

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the space of polynomials of degree at most $4$ with real coefficients $P_4[x],$ with inner product is defined as: $$\langle m,n\rangle = \int_0^1m(x)n(x)dx.$$ Let $U$ be a subspace of $P_4[x]$ consisting of polynomial $0$ and all polynomials with degree $0$.  I need to find a basis for $U^⊥$

Can someone help me with this? I don't have any idea how to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

$U^\perp$ is the space of all $m(x)\in P_4[x]$ such that $\langle m,u\rangle=0$ for all $u\in U=\Bbb R$. Since $\{1\}$ is a basis for $U$, then we need only determine a basis for the space of all $m(x)\in P_4[x]$ such that $\langle m,1\rangle=0$. For all $m\in\Bbb P_4[x]$ we have $$\langle m,1\rangle=\int_0^1 m(x)\,dx,$$ so we need only find $4$ linearly independent polynomials $p$ in $P_4[x]$ such that $$\int_0^1 p(x)dx=0.\tag{#}$$ Note that if $q(x)$ is an odd polynomial (a polynomial with only odd-degree terms), then $p(x)=q(x-\frac12)$ satisfies $(\#)$.* That alone gives you two elements for a basis, so you just need to find two more. Ideally, you want to find a quadratic and a quartic to complete the job.

Alternately, start with the basis $\{1,x,x^2,x^3,x^4\}$ for $P_4[x]$ and convert to an orthonormal basis including $1$ using Gram-Schmidt method. Removing $1$ from the resulting basis will yield a basis for $U^\perp$.

---

*Indeed, if $q(x)$ is *any* odd function--meaning $q(-x)=-q(x)$ for all $x$--and $q$ is integrable on $[-r,r]$ for some $r>0$, then we have $$\begin{align}\int_{-r}^r q(x)\,dx &= \int_{-r}^0q(x)\,dx +\int_0^rq(x)\,dx\\ &= -\int_0^{-r}q(x)\,dx+\int_0^rq(x)\,dx\\ &= -\int_0^{-r}q\bigl(-(-x)\bigr)\,dx+\int_0^rq(x)\,dx\\ &= -\int_0^{-r}q(-x)\,(-dx)+\int_0^rq(x)\,dx\\ &= -\int_0^{-r}q(-x)\,d(-x)+\int_0^rq(x)\,dx,\end{align}$$ and substitution $x\mapsto-x$ in the left-hand integral on the last line yields $$\int_{-r}^r q(x)\,dx=-\int_0^rq(x)\,dx+\int_0^rq(x)\,dx=0.$$ (This is even easier to see from the standpoint of symmetry: since the function takes on precisely opposite values as we move left or right from the $y$-axis, then whatever net signed area there is under the function's graph on the right side of the $y$-axis, we have exactly the opposite net signed area to the left side of the $y$-axis, so they completely cancel out.)

Since $0=\int_{-r}^rq(x)\,dx=\int_{-r}^rq(x)\,d(x+r),$ then the substitution $x\mapsto x-r$ in the right-most integral gives us $$0=\int_0^{2r}q(x-r)\,dx.$$ The note I made above is simply a special case of this fact, with $r=\frac12$ and $q$ an odd polynomial.

Comment: Gram Schmidt is really ugly for this one (If you need to calculate it on your own)

Comment: If Gram Schmidt is ugly.. can you explain the part about q(x) ad the quadratics.. I'm confused as to where you got this

Comment: @rt23: I added an explanation for the $q(x)$ part to the answer. As for the quadratic and quartic, the note hints at how to find a linear and cubic polynomial in the space, and we know that we need $4$ basis elements for $U^\perp,$ since $P_4[x]$ has dimension $5$ and $U$ has dimension $1$. If we can find a quadratic and a quartic in $U^\perp$, then we *know* that they are linearly independent from each other, and from the linear and cubic we found earlier, since they all have different degrees. Hence, the four of them together comprise a basis for $U^\perp.$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Note that $\langle p(x),c\rangle=c\langle p(x),1\rangle$ so that $\langle p(x),c\rangle=0$ for all $c$ if and only if $\langle p(x),1\rangle=0$. This gives you an equation for what $p(x)$ can be--now find a basis for this space!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Gram Schmidt to find an orthogonal Basis of $P_4[x]$. This will always work, but you make your hands dirty.

An orthogonal basis would be: 
$$1,\quad \sqrt{3} (2 x-1), \quad 
\sqrt{5} (6 (x-1) x+1), \quad \sqrt{7} (2 x-1) (10 (x-1) x+1),\quad 3 (10 (x-1) x (7 (x-1) x+2)+1)$$